# Using patent US 4582096 A in commercial?

Tags: patent-infringement, us4582096

Can I use the  (Hand loom provided with a mechanism for variation of the distance between breast beam and back beam 
US 4582096 A) patent in commercial issues?
 US-4582096-A

Answer (score 0):

This patent has expired (probably in 2003). The patent was granted in 1986 so its term was 17 years from grant date. Since 1995, the rules on patent terms have changed so they are now 20 years from the priority date. You are allowed to use the technology described in the patent without taking a license. In case you make any improvements to the technology, you should be aware that other patents potentially may still be in effect so a patent search is always a good idea.